# GetPixels based from a specific part of image across various screen sizes/aspect ratios

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coordinates, texture2d

I've done research and couldn't find the proper answer to my exact need so thought I will give this a go.

As per the subject, I need to get the pixels of say 32 x 32 block of a rendered screenshot which is an area of the image where I initially provide pixel cordinates and then I run a check to see if the pixels have a certain color. The image at start on play will fill the screen based on the screen size.

At the moment I can successfully grab the pixels and even evaluate the colors of that area to fulfill my task. And also even save it to drive as png.

My issue I ran into is though.. that the pixels cordinates won't be relevant to match the area of the image I want to grab the pixels on various screensizes/aspect ratios. Because the portion I want to grab pixels from the image gets scaled and moved. Since the image fills up the screen.

This is where I need help with. How I can I fetch the pixel cordinates (into GetPixels) of that area of the image matched (or scaled) accordingly to the current screensize and aspect ratio?

Comment: In Windows 10 you can get the scale factor (100%, 125%, ...) , and the display metrics for the screen resolution.  That's a starting point.

Comment: Extremely hard to tell without having your code .. but if you say it always fills the screen you could probably use [`Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint.html) and [`Camera.ViewportToScreenPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportToScreenPoint.html) in order to convert between pixels and a normalized Viewport position (goes from 0,0 bottom left to 1,1 top right corner of the screen)

Comment: @derHugo hmm haven't tried ViewportToScreenPoint yet, but I did try with WorldToScreenPoint. I attached empty game objects on the image and then tried feeding it's  world coordinates. But that always messed it up, always gave the wrong position of the image and even an offset didn't solve. Which is why I am now manually providing pixel cordinates initially and trying to find a way how that can scale according to screensizes. Okay so I will try editing my question to add the codes

Comment: Well I guess if you have a screen resolution you know the pixel coordinates for you could easily calculate them for all stretched display sizes ... or use the ViewportToScreenPoint which already does exactly that for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to the responses I received regarding my question. I decided to post an answer for myself because again after a bit more thought into it, I managed to find a working solution to my problem. Which is:..

Regardless of screen size,

1. I take a render of the screen
2. Rescale it to 1920 x 1080
3. Feed the same Px cordinates into Texture.GetPixels of the portions I want to check

Now everything is working fine ^^